# Long modular arithmetic going wrong

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have attempted to do a question that I crafted by hand: 6239^5 mod 15367

I know that 15367 is made up of prime numbers, notably 121 and 127.

Hence, I break it down by doing 6239^5 mod 121 and 6239^5 mod 127 individually. This yields the following results

```
6239^5 mod 121 = 109
6239^5 mod 127 = 64
```

Now I know that x is congruent in the following way:

```
x ≡ 109 (mod 121)
x ≡ 64 (mod 127)
```

As such this can then be calculated as:

```
109 + 121k ≡ 64 (mod 127)
121k (mod 127) ≡ (64-109) (mod 127)
121k (mod 127) ≡ -45 (mod 127)
-6k ≡ -45 (mod 127)
k = 45/6

So we substitute the k into the first formula:
109 + 121k
= 109 + 121(45/6 + 127u)
= 109 + 907.5 + 127u.
```

I'm stuck now because 907.5 is a decimal.

How do I now work out the final answer?

Comment: note:  on your last line with the gray background $121\times127u$ should be $15367u$ (not $127u$), but that can be ignored modulo $15367$

Answer (score 2):

$$-6k\equiv-45\mod 127$$

$$2k\equiv15\equiv142 \mod 127$$

$$k\equiv71\mod 127$$

Comment: what I wrote should help you work out the final answer; let me know if you have further questions

Answer (score -1):

One never writes fractions in modular arithmetic. So where you went wrong is on the line $k = 45/6$.

Instead, one computes the multiplicative inverse of $6$ modulo 127. Let's call that number $x$ (you can compute it for yourself or look it up somehow).

Then you would instead have 
$$-6k  \equiv -45 \pmod {127}
$$
$$6k \equiv 45  \pmod {127}
$$
$$k \equiv 45x  \pmod {127}
$$
and carry on from there.

Comment: you can use fractions, but you must be be careful.

Comment: It is not true that "one never writes fractions in modular arithmetic". But some authors prefer to not introduce them at elementary levels - postponing them till students know some algebra (esp. the universal property of rings of fractions and localizations).

Comment: $${45\over 6}\equiv {15\over 2}\equiv {-112\over 2}\equiv -56\equiv 71 \bmod 127$$